# Process flag before others regardless of order

Tags: bash, macos

I'm writing a script to sync databases from remote to local, and optionally between remote environments. I need to process the flag to sync between remote environments before I execute the sync commands, but if I use the standard `while getopts ... case` that I've seen in many answers here, the order of the flags. So, how do I trap the flag that will indicate remote environment syncing (and the value of which environment to sync) before processing all of the other flags?

```
dest='local'

if [ has_param "p" ]
  
fi

if [ $# -eq 0 ];
then
  usage
  exit 0
else
  while getopts 'wnechsp:' flag; do
    case "${flag}" in
      p)  dest=$OPTARG ;;
      w)  sync_www "$dest" ;;
      n)  sync_news ;;
      e)  sync_express ;;
      c)  sync_catalog ;;
      g)  sync_handbook ;;
      s)  sync_sites ;;
    esac
  done
fi
```

In this state, if I call this script like this: `sync.bash -w -p stage` `$dest` remains set to the default "local" when I call the function `sync_www "$dest"`. But if I call the script like this: `sync.bash -pstage -w` then `$dest` gets changed to 'stage' before i call `sync_www "$dest"`. So, I need to always process the `-p` flag first, to see if it has a value, and set `$dest` to that value before processing any other flags.

I found another answer to detect the presence of a specific flag, but not retrieve it's value:

```
has_param() {
  local term="$1"
  shift
  for arg; do
    if [[ $arg == "$term" ]]; then
      return 0
    fi
  done
  return 1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Parse your options first, *then* act.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# This example uses no default dest value,
# and expects the user to use -p to set it.
unset dest

do_sync_news=false
do_sync_express=false
do_sync_catalog=false
do_sync_handbook=false
do_sync_sites=false

while getopts 'wnechsp:' flag; do
        case $flag in
                p)  dest=$OPTARG ;;
                w)  do_sync_www=true ;;
                n)  do_sync_news=true ;;
                e)  do_sync_express=true ;;
                c)  do_sync_catalog=true ;;
                g)  do_sync_handbook=true ;;
                s)  do_sync_sites=true ;;
                *)  echo 'error' >&2; exit 1
        esac
done

shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

if [ -z "$dest" ]; then
        echo 'No destination (-p)' >&2
        exit 1
fi

"$do_sync_www"   &&  sync_www "$dest"
"$do_sync_news"  &&  sync_news "$dest"
# etc.
```

A useful flow is

1. Set default values to flag variables etc.
2. Parse command line options, updating flag variables etc.
3. Sanity check the state of flag variables etc. after option parsing. This is where you act on invalid or missing values or conflicting options.
4. Act with flag variables etc. taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
actions=
add_action() {
  actions="$actions
  $1"
}

while getopts 'wnechsp:' flag; do
    case "${flag}" in
      p)  dest=$OPTARG ;;
      w)  add_action 'sync_www "$dest"' ;;
      n)  add_action sync_news ;;
      e)  add_action sync_express ;;
      c)  add_action sync_catalog ;;
      g)  add_action sync_handbook ;;
      s)  add_action sync_sites ;;
    esac
done
eval "$actions"
```

That would ensure `$dest` is set first (possibly several times, each one overriding the previous), and actions done later (possibly several times) in the order specified by the user.